# How do I force my UIViewController view's initial size to match its nib?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In my `UIViewController`'s `nib`, I specify a custom size (743x533) for `view`, but when I instantiate my `UIViewController`, its `view`'s size is always 768x1024. How do I force its size to (743x533)? I don't want to have to specify this size in two places (in code after I instantiate my `UIViewController` and in my `UIViewController`'s `nib`).

Answer (score 0):

From the [`UIViewController` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A view controller is usually owned by a window or another view
>   controller. If a view controller is owned by a window object, it acts
>   as the window’s root view controller. The view controller’s root view
>   is added as a subview of the window and resized to fill the window.

So, unless you are displaying it modally, it is going to take up the full screen.

If this isn't what you want, you can either create a container view which can have multiple UIViewController's inside it where you can specify the size, or this should just be a UIView which is added to an existing view controller.

Comment: This is before I add it to the window. I just do `[[MyViewController new] view].frame` and I expect that to return a rect with size (743x533).

Comment: A view's size is not set (and can not be reliably used) until viewDidAppear is called.

Comment: Is there documentation or a link to the mailing list or forums supporting this?